# Loading a logged in page in an iframe

Tags: cookies, crossdomain, clickjacking, cross-frame-scripting

Suppose `www.youtube.com` have no `X-Frame-Options` set.

Imagine I'm already logged in to YouTube. Now from another web page in the same browser I'm loading YouTube in an iframe, will the browser send all the auth-cookies to the YouTube loaded in the iframe so that it will be loaded as logged in?

Comment: How about making a simple webpage with YouTube in an iframe and see what happens?

Answer (score 1):

By default, yes, though the sandbox parameter in the iframe tag can change this behavior.